# slow single connection between two otherwise fast machines

Tags: linux, networking, performance, iperf

I'm having trouble with larger file transfers from one of our virtual servers to our office network. The virtual server acts as a VPN server, therefore we call it "VPN", but the usage of VPN is not of issue here, I used direct connections for the file transfer. The machine uses Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS if that's of any matter.

Now, the upload speed of the VPN server is around 71,20 Mbit/s whereas the download speed for our internet gateway for our office network (called alix, runs on Debian 6) can handle around ~86,31 Mbit/s by default (It's a 100 Mbit line). I tested those speeds multiple times with using `speedtest-cli`, which uses speedtest.net servers. The ping is around 35-44 ms.

When I used `iperf` I got transfer rates between 20,7 Mbit/s and 35,7 Mbit/s. Multiple connections with `iperf` maxed out the available bandwidth. So the issue might be the TCP window size (as seen on [other topics](https://serverfault.com/questions/592172/debugging-slow-transfer-rate-from-server)) and it's not that there's much traffic on the line by default. I used a window size calculator and now know I need roughly 400KB for the window size. So I changed the respecitve settings on both ends (net.core.rmem and wmem, net.ipv4.tcp_rmem and wmem), but it got even worse (~ 4 to 9Mbit/s). We're not having any packet drops or anything. TCP window scaling is enabled on both machines. There's no firewall throttling on both ends.

What can I do to further narrow down the cause or even already improve the throughput? Thanks for your help.